# How to write test case for Run time Assembly Location

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Here is my class which create new application instance:

```
public interface IApplicationInstanceProvider
{
    bool CreateNewProcess();
}

public class ApplicationInstanceProvider : IApplicationInstanceProvider
{
    public bool CreateNewProcess()
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
        return p.Start();
    }
}
```

Here is my test case:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethodForAppInstance()
{
    IApplicationInstanceProvider provider = new ApplicationInstanceProvider();
    bool isCreated = provider.CreateNewProcess();

    Assert.AreEqual(isCreated,true);
}
```

Here is problem: `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` is null while test case execution. But it works fine while application running.
Please help!

Comment: IMO it depends on what you want to test. You may abstract all _shared_ code in ApplicationInstanceProvider into a base class and create a mock for testing where you create an instance of a known executable...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I want to test if `CreateNewProcess()` returns true or not..

Comment: That method does two things, namely find the entry assembly's location and start a Process instance with that location (i.e. it starts another instance of the current executable). Two things is one too many. Refactor the method.

Comment: @CodeCaster So refactoring method isnt solve issue, please dont say you have to mock find executable location method this with dummy know path. Ahh itz not required here, I guess there isnt any known executable path here...!

Comment: I'm not really sure what that means.

Comment: @AnkushMadankar it's not clear what you mean in your comment. Your class run a new instance of entry assembly, _obviously_ it's not viable for tests (because code isn't executed by your app and you don't even _know_ who is your host) then what you **should** do is refactoring (yes!). First extract code to start a new process into a separate method and introduce a base class. Then create a derived class where program path is resolved using entry assembly. It's not testable then you introduce a new derived class (only for testing purposes) that executes (and then close!!!) notepad.exe.

Comment: What I mean with _obviously_ is that you can't test whole method. However it does two things (I'm not suggesting to be _integralist_ about this but if you want to do unit testing then you have to): 1) execute a process and 2) determine program path. Now 1) can be tested for sure while for 2) you probably can't...

Comment: I agree with @AdrianoRepetti and CodeCaster, however there is an additional way to test your method behaviour using MsFakes. the important thing to check in your method is: the process start with entry assembly location. so stub process and the assembly location and then verify that the process was started with the right location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't test your class as-is because you're executing an *unknown* new process in the test environment. It's not viable because:

1. `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` will return `null`.
2. Whatever it returns you'll execute *that* process and it may be, let's say, `devenv.exe`, `chrome.exe` or whatever.

`CreateNewProcess()` method does many things: it determines program to execute path and it run it. Moreover its return value tells caller if a **new** process has been started or an **existing one has been reused**. Too many things for a single method make it hard to test. Fortunately there are at least two approaches to make your code testable: create a specialized `ApplicationInstanceProvider` class for testing or make a separate class for it.

**Let's see FIRST METHOD:**

```
public class ApplicationInstanceProvider : IApplicationInstanceProvider {
    public bool CreateNewProcess() {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = ResolveApplicationPath();
        return process.Start();
    }

    protected virtual string ResolveApplicationPath() {
        return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
    }
}
```

You'll create a derived class for testing:

```
sealed class TestApplicationInstanceProvider : ApplicationInstanceProvider {
    protected override string ResolveApplicationPath() {
        // path to your assembly or a well-known executable executable
        // Like %WINDIR%\notepad.exe
        return "...";
    }
}
```

It'll be then used like this in your test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethodForAppInstance() {
    var provider = new TestApplicationInstanceProvider();
    bool isCreated = provider.CreateNewProcess();

    Assert.AreEqual(isCreated, true);
}
```

Note that you **cannot** test `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` but you can test everything els. Note that now you're testing if you create a new process instance but you do not check you started *right* one; this will increase code coverage but **you're actually testing almost nothing** because `Process.Start()` will always return true for executables (running process *may* be reused for documents). That's why you have to split `CreateNewProcess()` responsabilities (not only for clarity but for testing). Do not forget to close process instance in your cleanup method after testing!

**Let's see SECOND METHOD:** second method is little bit more complicated but it's more versatile:

```
public interface IAssemblyResolver {
    string GetEntryAssemblyPath();
}

public sealed class DefaultAssemblyResolver : IAssemblyResolver {
    public string GetEntryAssemblyPath() {
        return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
    }
}

public class ApplicationInstanceProvider : IApplicationInstanceProvider {
    public ApplicationInstanceProvider(IAssemblyResolver resolver) {
        _resolver = resolver;
    }

    public bool CreateNewProcess() {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = _resolver.GetEntryAssemblyPath();
        return process.Start();
    }

    private readonly IAssemblyResolver _resolver;
}
```

Now you have to create a mock for testing:

```
sealed class TestAssemblyResolver : IAssemblyResolver {
    public string GetEntryAssemblyPath() {
        // Return path of a well-known test application,
        // for example an "empty" console application. You can also
        // reuse it to, for example, return different error codes
        return Assembly.Load(...);
    }
}
```

Test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethodForAppInstance() {
    var resolver = new TestAssemblyResolver();
    var provider = new ApplicationInstanceProvider(resolver);
    bool isCreated = provider.CreateNewProcess();

    Assert.AreEqual(isCreated, true);
}
```

What your *fake* application may look like?

```
static class Program {
    static int Main(string[] args) {
        if (args.Length == 0)
            return 0;

        return Int32.Parse(args[0]);
    }
}
```